# java getter overloading

Tags: java

Why I cannot overload class member of type JTextField in a following fashion:
`

```
private JTextField m_oFilename=new JTextField();
    public JTextField filename()
        { return this.m_oFilename; }
    public String filename()
        { return this.m_oFilename.getText(); }
```

Comment: To me, `filename()` should return `String`. The other method should be renamed, perhaps `filenameField()`. Better yet, to adhere to standard getter naming, use `getFilename()` and `getFilenameField()`.

Comment: In my code, I avoid my methods naming beginning with "get", so I can quickly distinct java sdk method from my custom method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, overloading refers to methods of the same name that have different method signatures.  However, the return type is *not* part of the method signature.

The compiler must know which return type to resolve, and if the method signatures are the same, then it can't tell them apart or know which to use, so [this is disallowed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2), per JLS 8.4.2.

Comment: For example, suppose you wrote `Object o = m_oFilename.filename()`.  Which overload would be called?

Comment: @MarkoFrelih: Any fix, using generic types or not, will have to either use different method names or different _argument_ types.

Comment: Due to type erasure, any generic return type would become an `Object` and then even the return types would be the same.

Comment: Hmm, I think both of you are right :). So, there is really not any way to do this. I would like to avoid renaming method, because the code is ugly then ...

Answer (score 2):

Because it doesn't use the output of a method to determine which method it should call.

For example, which method should run if you just executed:

```
m_oFilename.filename();
```

The compiler wouldn't know which to run, so this can't compile.